# AWS Lambda - Source of Errors?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

AWS Lambda provides a CloudWatch/All Metrics/ Dashboard called "Error count and success rate (%)".

[image]

The link to this Dashboard is available from AWS Lambda/Dashboard/Error count and success rate (%)/View in metrics.  Tip click the hamburger in the Error graph, top right.

Question:
I am looking for the source of the Lambdas' error/s (there could be 1 or hundreds of functions) that contribute to the creation of the Errors?

Why:
I need the list of Lambda functions that are throwing errors (for me they are typically timeouts), but these errors we want to track may change over time.

What I could do:
I could create a specific CloudWatch rule for each Lambda function.  This is not efficient as there maybe 100's +++ of functions.  I could also use the CDLI however this is limited to a maximum of 20x CloudWatch Logs ie:

> aws logs start-query --log-group-name
> /aws/lambda/lambdaFunction1020 --start-time 1646185910 --end-time
> 1646358710 --query-string 'fields @timestamp, @message | filter
> @message like "Task timed out" | sort @timestamp desc | limit 20'

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch-metrics-insights-buildquery.html

Go to: Cloudwatch/All Metrics/Query and use the following SQL.  From what I can see there are no LIMITS on the number of results returned.  The only issue I have found is the time frame is limited to a maximum of three (3) hours.

```
SELECT SUM(Errors)
FROM SCHEMA("AWS/Lambda", FunctionName)
GROUP BY FunctionName
ORDER BY SUM() DESC
LIMIT 10
```

There is also a number of pre-built queries under "Add query" for many AWS services...